# WordPress theme with two languages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, backend

If i have two button in front-end called English and Arabic, what is the best practice to make the website displayed by the language user chooses.

Comment: personally, I would use https://wpml.org/ plugin - It makes it easy to create your website in multiple languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd stay away from a heavy plugin like wpml which creates duplicate posts and run slow queries. The plus side is really so you can use the plugin with other WPML compatible plugins (there are some popular plugins compatible with it) and translate taxonomies and syncing metadata in translation posts.

If the translation is minimal on some content and you can code yourself, I'd suggest making your custom solutions by maybe storing data as metadata associated with post and display according to the language setting.